# How to generate Java client from WSDL with Tomcat 8.0? WSDL file has multiple xsd import

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, xsd, wsdl

I am doing Migration of my project from IBM WebSphere to Tomcat 8.0, I am facing issue to generate client from WSDL. I have tried with WSDL2Java but this WSDL files have multiple xsd files as import. I am unable to generate all the java files from this WSDL. Any help will be appreciated

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.4-b01-. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://example.com/" name="WS_50" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://example.com" schemaLocation="WS50_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://dummy.com" schemaLocation="WS50_schema2.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://dummy123.com" schemaLocation="WS50_schema3.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="createPart">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns1:createPart" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="createPartResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns2:createPartResponse" xmlns:ns2="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getFileList">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns3:getFileList" xmlns:ns3="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getFileListResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns4:getFileListResponse" xmlns:ns4="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListBasicPart">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns5:getListBasicPart" xmlns:ns5="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListBasicPartResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns6:getListBasicPartResponse" xmlns:ns6="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListBasicUser">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns7:getListBasicUser" xmlns:ns7="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListBasicUserResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns8:getListBasicUserResponse" xmlns:ns8="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListBasicUserList">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns9:getListBasicUserList" xmlns:ns9="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListBasicUserListResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns10:getListBasicUserListResponse" xmlns:ns10="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListDesignControl">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns11:getListDesignControl" xmlns:ns11="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListDesignControlResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns12:getListDesignControlResponse" xmlns:ns12="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListGeographicalRestriction">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns13:getListGeographicalRestriction" xmlns:ns13="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListGeographicalRestrictionResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns14:getListGeographicalRestrictionResponse" xmlns:ns14="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListLanguageCode">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns15:getListLanguageCode" xmlns:ns15="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListLanguageCodeResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns16:getListLanguageCodeResponse" xmlns:ns16="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListMachineCriticalCode">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns17:getListMachineCriticalCode" xmlns:ns17="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListMachineCriticalCodeResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns18:getListMachineCriticalCodeResponse" xmlns:ns18="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListManufacturer">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns19:getListManufacturer" xmlns:ns19="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListManufacturerResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns20:getListManufacturerResponse" xmlns:ns20="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListMaterialCode">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns21:getListMaterialCode" xmlns:ns21="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListMaterialCodeResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns22:getListMaterialCodeResponse" xmlns:ns22="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListPartClassification">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns23:getListPartClassification" xmlns:ns23="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListPartClassificationResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns24:getListPartClassificationResponse" xmlns:ns24="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListPrimaryUse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns25:getListPrimaryUse" xmlns:ns25="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListPrimaryUseResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns26:getListPrimaryUseResponse" xmlns:ns26="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListReplenishmentSource">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns27:getListReplenishmentSource" xmlns:ns27="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListReplenishmentSourceResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns28:getListReplenishmentSourceResponse" xmlns:ns28="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListTermCode">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns29:getListTermCode" xmlns:ns29="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListTermCodeResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns30:getListTermCodeResponse" xmlns:ns30="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListTermCodeDetails">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns31:getListTermCodeDetails" xmlns:ns31="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListTermCodeDetailsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns32:getListTermCodeDetailsResponse" xmlns:ns32="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListUniCodeTermCode">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns33:getListUniCodeTermCode" xmlns:ns33="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListUniCodeTermCodeResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns34:getListUniCodeTermCodeResponse" xmlns:ns34="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListUniCodeTermCodeDetails">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns35:getListUniCodeTermCodeDetails" xmlns:ns35="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListUniCodeTermCodeDetailsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns36:getListUniCodeTermCodeDetailsResponse" xmlns:ns36="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListUnitCode">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns37:getListUnitCode" xmlns:ns37="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListUnitCodeResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns38:getListUnitCodeResponse" xmlns:ns38="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getPartClassification">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns39:getPartClassification" xmlns:ns39="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getPartClassificationResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns40:getPartClassificationResponse" xmlns:ns40="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getPingMessage">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns41:getPingMessage" xmlns:ns41="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getPingMessageResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns42:getPingMessageResponse" xmlns:ns42="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="processDesignControlTransfer">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns43:processDesignControlTransfer" xmlns:ns43="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="processDesignControlTransferResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns44:processDesignControlTransferResponse" xmlns:ns44="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="updateListPart">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns45:updateListPart" xmlns:ns45="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="updateListPartResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns46:updateListPartResponse" xmlns:ns46="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="updateListPartUser">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns47:updateListPartUser" xmlns:ns47="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="updateListPartUserResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns48:updateListPartUserResponse" xmlns:ns48="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="updatePartList">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns49:updatePartList" xmlns:ns49="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="updatePartListResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns50:updatePartListResponse" xmlns:ns50="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListPartPrefix">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns51:getListPartPrefix" xmlns:ns51="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getListPartPrefixResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns52:getListPartPrefixResponse" xmlns:ns52="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="createDRPPart">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns53:createDRPPart" xmlns:ns53="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="createDRPPartResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns54:createDRPPartResponse" xmlns:ns54="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="createManufacturerPart">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns55:createManufacturerPart" xmlns:ns55="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
  <message name="createManufacturerPartResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="ns56:createManufacturerPartResponse" xmlns:ns56="http://example.com"/>
  </message>
    <!-- added for updateSupplierPart message requirement -->
    <message name="updateSupplierPart">
        <part name="parameters" element="ns57:updateSupplierPart"  xmlns:ns57="http://example.com"/>
    </message>
    <message name="updateSupplierPartResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="ns58:updateSupplierPartResponse" xmlns:ns58="http://example.com"/>
    </message>

  <portType name="WS_50">
    <operation name="createPart">
      <input message="tns:createPart"/>
      <output message="tns:createPartResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getFileList">
      <input message="tns:getFileList"/>
      <output message="tns:getFileListResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListBasicPart">
      <input message="tns:getListBasicPart"/>
      <output message="tns:getListBasicPartResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListBasicUser">
      <input message="tns:getListBasicUser"/>
      <output message="tns:getListBasicUserResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListBasicUserList">
      <input message="tns:getListBasicUserList"/>
      <output message="tns:getListBasicUserListResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListDesignControl">
      <input message="tns:getListDesignControl"/>
      <output message="tns:getListDesignControlResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListGeographicalRestriction">
      <input message="tns:getListGeographicalRestriction"/>
      <output message="tns:getListGeographicalRestrictionResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListLanguageCode">
      <input message="tns:getListLanguageCode"/>
      <output message="tns:getListLanguageCodeResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListMachineCriticalCode">
      <input message="tns:getListMachineCriticalCode"/>
      <output message="tns:getListMachineCriticalCodeResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListManufacturer">
      <input message="tns:getListManufacturer"/>
      <output message="tns:getListManufacturerResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListMaterialCode">
      <input message="tns:getListMaterialCode"/>
      <output message="tns:getListMaterialCodeResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListPartClassification">
      <input message="tns:getListPartClassification"/>
      <output message="tns:getListPartClassificationResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListPrimaryUse">
      <input message="tns:getListPrimaryUse"/>
      <output message="tns:getListPrimaryUseResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListReplenishmentSource">
      <input message="tns:getListReplenishmentSource"/>
      <output message="tns:getListReplenishmentSourceResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListTermCode">
      <input message="tns:getListTermCode"/>
      <output message="tns:getListTermCodeResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListTermCodeDetails">
      <input message="tns:getListTermCodeDetails"/>
      <output message="tns:getListTermCodeDetailsResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListUniCodeTermCode">
      <input message="tns:getListUniCodeTermCode"/>
      <output message="tns:getListUniCodeTermCodeResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListUniCodeTermCodeDetails">
      <input message="tns:getListUniCodeTermCodeDetails"/>
      <output message="tns:getListUniCodeTermCodeDetailsResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListUnitCode">
      <input message="tns:getListUnitCode"/>
      <output message="tns:getListUnitCodeResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getPartClassification">
      <input message="tns:getPartClassification"/>
      <output message="tns:getPartClassificationResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getPingMessage">
      <input message="tns:getPingMessage"/>
      <output message="tns:getPingMessageResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="processDesignControlTransfer">
      <input message="tns:processDesignControlTransfer"/>
      <output message="tns:processDesignControlTransferResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateListPart">
      <input message="tns:updateListPart"/>
      <output message="tns:updateListPartResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateListPartUser">
      <input message="tns:updateListPartUser"/>
      <output message="tns:updateListPartUserResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updatePartList">
      <input message="tns:updatePartList"/>
      <output message="tns:updatePartListResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListPartPrefix">
      <input message="tns:getListPartPrefix"/>
      <output message="tns:getListPartPrefixResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="createDRPPart">
      <input message="tns:createDRPPart"/>
      <output message="tns:createDRPPartResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="createManufacturerPart">
      <input message="tns:createManufacturerPart"/>
      <output message="tns:createManufacturerPartResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <!-- added for updateSupplierPart message requirement -->
        <operation name="updateSupplierPart">
            <input message="tns:updateSupplierPart"/>
            <output message="tns:updateSupplierPartResponse"/>
        </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="WS_50PortBinding" type="tns:WS_50">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="createPart">
      <soap:operation soapAction="createPart"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getFileList">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getFileList"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListBasicPart">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListBasicPart"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListBasicUser">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListBasicUser"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListBasicUserList">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListBasicUserList"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListDesignControl">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListDesignControl"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListGeographicalRestriction">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListGeographicalRestriction"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListLanguageCode">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListLanguageCode"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListMachineCriticalCode">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListMachineCriticalCode"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListManufacturer">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListManufacturer"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListMaterialCode">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListMaterialCode"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListPartClassification">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListPartClassification"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListPrimaryUse">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListPrimaryUse"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListReplenishmentSource">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListReplenishmentSource"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListTermCode">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListTermCode"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListTermCodeDetails">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListTermCodeDetails"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListUniCodeTermCode">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListUniCodeTermCode"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListUniCodeTermCodeDetails">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListUniCodeTermCodeDetails"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListUnitCode">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListUnitCode"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getPartClassification">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getPartClassification"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getPingMessage">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getPingMessage"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="processDesignControlTransfer">
      <soap:operation soapAction="processDesignControlTransfer"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateListPart">
      <soap:operation soapAction="updateListPart"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateListPartUser">
      <soap:operation soapAction="updateListPartUser"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updatePartList">
      <soap:operation soapAction="updatePartList"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getListPartPrefix">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getListPartPrefix"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="createDRPPart">
      <soap:operation soapAction="createDRPPart"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="createManufacturerPart">
      <soap:operation soapAction="createManufacturerPart"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <!-- added for updateSupplierPart message requirement -->
        <operation name="updateSupplierPart">
            <soap:operation soapAction="updateSupplierPart"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="WS_50">
    <port name="WS_50Port" binding="tns:WS_50PortBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: What error do you get or what is the concrete difficulty you face/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use "wsimport" on the command prompt, like this:

```
wsimport -s F:\temp -p cn.ljl.sand.jws.chapter3.client.wsimport http://localhost:6666/service/interpret?wsdl
```

Detailed wsimport options, please refer to the following URL:
[wsimport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html)

Note: make sure that you have added the wsimport folder to your path.

Hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks for response, But as i am using Tomcat 8.0 this approach is not working for me. If you have any other idea to generate then please let me know.